# Adding spinner to Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I am trying add Spinner in to my Lightning component and it is not working as expected. Below is what I tried when the button is clicked it needs to shows the spinner and disable the spinner  once the click even is completed.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global"  >

 <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="form" 
        objectApiName="Case" 
        recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
        onerror="{!c.handleError}"
        onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
         <!--<lightning:spinner aura:id="spinner" variant="brand" /> -->
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="statusInput" fieldName="Status" class="slds-hide" />
        <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" label="Close Case(LDS)" />
 </lightning:recordEditForm>    

    <div class="exampleHolder">
        <aura:if isTrue="{! v.loaded }">
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" />
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.loaded', component.get('v.loaded'));
        event.preventDefault();      
        var fields = event.getParam('fields');
        fields.Status = 'Closed';
        console.log(JSON.stringify(fields)); 
        component.find('form').submit(fields); 
        
    },
    
    handleError: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.loaded', !component.get('v.loaded'));
        $A.get("e.force:showToast")
        .setParams({
            type: 'error',
            mode: 'pester',
            message: 'Case cannot be closed, please verify the required fields like Category are filled !!' }).fire();  
    },
    
    handleSuccess: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.loaded', !component.get('v.loaded'));
            $A.get("e.force:showToast")
            .setParams({
            type: 'success',
            message: 'Case is closed!',
            mode: 'pester'
            })
        .fire();
    }
})
```

I was hoping the spinner will be shown when the button is clicked until the toast of success/error is fired. But it shows on the page load itself like below

[image]

Can anyone help me what I am missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the markup and js controller it seems like you have not actually set the value of 'loaded' attribute anywhere. Because the default value is **false** for the **loaded** attribute, that's why you are seeing it on the page load.
So, This can be resolved using two approaches, if we go with the current one then the loaded attribute should have a default value **true** and then you have to explicitly **set** the value of  attribute as true or false when your button event gets fired --> **component.set('v.loaded',false)** and when you are done with the processing update the loaded attribute again --> **component.set('v.loaded',true)**.

I suggest instead of using aura:if, you can use spinner out of the recordEditForm component and use slds classes to display or  hide the spinner:
here keeping the default value for loaded as false

```
<aura:attribute name="loaded" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<<lightning:spinner variant="brand" alternativeText="Loading..." class="{!(v.loaded? 'slds-show': 'slds-hide')}" />>
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="form" > ....</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

so just update the values of **loaded** attribute to true or false depending upon the operation.